# Data frame error when trying to do histogram

Tags: r, r-markdown

I converted [https://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/sexlierel.dat](https://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Ewinner/data/sexlierel.dat) into a csv file. How would I do a histogram like this https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/73b1aa01f56fdebb5829f8bb9efefd2d424165dd/0799c/eda_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-6-1.png? When I knit it gives me a data must be in data frame error.

````
    data_set <- read.csv("project_data.csv", header = TRUE)
     
    names(data_set)
    
    summary(data_set)
    
    summary(data_set$Gender)
    data=data.frame("Gender","Count")
    
    ```
    
    ```{r}
    plot_density(data_set)
    ggplot(data = "Gender") + geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = "Count"), binwidth = 1)
    scatter=ggplot(data=data, aes("Gender", "Count")) + geom_point()
    
    ```


  [1]: https://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/sexlierel.dat
  [2]: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/73b1aa01f56fdebb5829f8bb9efefd2d424165dd/0799c/eda_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-6-1.png
````

Comment: Welcome to SO, see how do I ask a good question [ask], see our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably closer to what you want:

```
data_set <- read.csv("project_data.csv", header = TRUE)
ggplot(data = data_set, aes(Gender)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
scatter = ggplot(data = data_set, aes(Gender, Count)) + geom_point()
```

This assumes there is a Count column in your data set. I don't know anything about `plot_density()` or what package it's from, so I have no advice about that.

Explanation of the other bits:

1. You don't need to call `data.frame()` to get your data into a data frame. `read.csv()` has already done that for you.
2. `data.frame()` doesn't work that way anyway; passing it "Gender" and "Count" just makes it construct an otherwise empty data frame with those two strings as cells. In my experience, calling `data.frame()` directly never does what I want it to, so I avoid it and use other functions that do that work for me.
3. `ggplot(data = "Gender")...` this part doesn't work because you are just giving ggplot a string instead of a data set.
4. `scatter = ggplot(data = data ...` this part would be fine, but `data` doesn't contain what you want because of #2 above.